# I need an RTOS with 10Gb Ethernet support

Tags: networking, operating-system, real-time

First, I apologize if this is in the wrong category, if you can direct me to a more appropriate forum or StackExchange site I'd appreciate it.

I am trying to make a real-time analysis box. Without going into too many details, the main limiting factor is it needs to use 10Gigabit ethernet. Can anyone suggest an RTOS that supports 10GbE, and an architecture that will run it?

I've been looking into many RTOSes over the past month, and none of the ones I've found will actually support 10Gb.

Comment: A general question - are you sure that you need a real real-time OS? - the term is often misused - i.e. do you need a fixed time preemptive scheduler or do you need a fast multi-threaded OS. The two are __not__ the same and the latter is often available free, the former rarely so.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the difference, and we need a deterministic, fixed-time system that is guaranteed to execute. There are actually a large number of open-source RTOSs out there, just none that work for my requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I am reasonably sure that [QNX](http://www.qnx.com/) can support 10 Gigabit Ethernet.  I found an experimental driver for Intel 10 gigabit controllers dated 2 years ago the their foundry area, [here](http://community.qnx.com/sf/go/wiki6010?nav=1), and several other references to other 10/100 Gigabit Ethernet devices on the site.